# Proof that $Y=A\cos(px)+B\sin(px)$ is only periodic if $p=n$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

I am asked to show that a function $y=A\cos(px)+B\sin(px)$ can only be periodic if $p$ is an integer $n$, where $A$, $B$ are arbitrary constants.

In other words $y(x)=y(x+2 \pi)$

I begin by solving for both sides of the equation:
$y(x)=A\cos(px)+B\sin(px)$

$y(x+2\pi)=A\cos(px+2\pi p)+ B\sin(px+2\pi p)$

According to the trigonometric identities $\cos(a+b)=\cos(a)\cos(b)-\sin(a)\sin(b)$

and $\sin(a+b)=\sin(a)\cos(b)+\cos(a)\sin(b)$

It follows that :

$A\cos(px+2\pi p)+ B\sin(px+2\pi p) = A[\cos(px)\cos(2\pi p)-\sin(px)\sin(2\pi p)] + B[\sin(px)\cos(2\pi p)+\cos(px)\sin(2\pi p)]$

My idea was then to equate the coefficients of $\cos(px)$ and $\sin(px)$ on both the left and right side of the expression; thus:

$A=A\cos(2\pi p)+B\sin(2\pi p)$ [1]

and

$B=-A\sin(2\pi p)+B\cos(2\pi p)$ [2]

dividing [1] by $A$ and [2] by $B$ yields:

$1=\cos(2\pi p)+B/A\sin(2\pi p)$ [3]

and

$1=-A/B\sin(2\pi p)+\cos(2\pi p)$ [4]

Subtracting 4 from 3 yields:

$0=(B/A+A/B)\sin(2\pi p)=0$

Clearly $A$ and $B$ can not be themselves zero; nor can the expression $(B/A+A/B)=0$

Hence:

$2\pi p=n \pi$ implying $p=n/2$

Can anybody find some error in my reasoning or point me in the correct direction?

Answer (score 0):

Does $Y$ need to have a period of $2\pi$? If $Y$ had a period of $\pi$, then how could you adapt your solution to show p is an integer?

Comment: This is an extension to an eigenvalue problem obtained from the laplace equation governing the steady state heat conduction of a disk. In fact Y is meant to be the angle theta; hence why it should have a period of 2$\pi$